# Any way to browse wifi Harddisk through iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, wifi

I am having a wifi Harddisk , just want to connect and access the folders and document of wifi Harddisk from my iPhone through wifi and without using internet connectivity.

I want to create similar application mentioned below url:-

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goflex-media-seagate-technology/id431912202?mt=8 ?

Comment: I believe this disks usually make use of FTP protocol - you can check that with connecting to your disk with FTP client. You'll need disk's IP&port and possibly login credentials. If that works you might want to look in this direction:[SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) Some of this disks might even support ZeroConf (Bonjour) so you could find them without user interaction.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this sample, but don't know how to access harddisk data..

Comment: It's almost certainly FTP protocol but you should confirm this with disk manufacturer. Which WiFi disk do you have?

Comment: disk is of **GoFlex Satellite** brand

Answer (score 1):

As per [GoFlex Satellite™ User Guide](http://www.seagate.com/files/support/external-products/network/satellite/_shared/docs/goflex-satellite-user-guide-en-us.pdf) you can browse the HD contents with a web browser.

You (or your user) will have to manually connect to GoFlex Satellite WiFi network - it looks like this device starts it's own AdHoc network. Sorry to say it's not possible to automate this process from code - at least not without using private API's.

You can test if this works like this:
- connect to GoFlex Satelliti WiFi network with your iPhone
- open www.goflexsatellite.com in Safari

You can do this also from code using [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

A nice tutorial on using `UIWebView` can be found [here](http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/) - just remember to use www.goflexsatellite.com as a target URL.

Comment: Thanks, I can access in webview but is there any way that I can access/browse created folder in device from uiwebview...??

Comment: Yes: there is a link to UIVebview tutorial in my answer. Instead of URL in tutorial you have to use the same URL that you use to browse the disk with a 'normal' browser.